# save picture to bmp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, save, paint

i have this code:

```
Dictionary<int, Class1> MyDict = new Dictionary<int, Class1>();
```

i get mouse position

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {               Mycl.X1 = e.X;
                    Mycl.X2 = e.Y;}
private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
                    Mycl.X3 = e.X;
                    Mycl.X4 = e.Y;
        MyDict.Add(MyDict.Count + 1, Mycl);
        panel1.Invalidate();
        Mycl = new Class1();
    }
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.BackgroundImage == null)
        {
            panel1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        }
        Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(panel1.BackgroundImage);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Class1> kvp in MyDict)
        {
            Point pl1 = new Point(MyDict[kvp.Key].X1, MyDict[kvp.Key].X2);
            Point pl2 = new Point(MyDict[kvp.Key].X3, MyDict[kvp.Key].X4);
            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(MyPen, pl1, pl2);
            G.DrawLine(MyPen, pl1, pl2);
        }
    }
```

but when I paint this picture, I have a trouble.

When I use `e.graphics.drawline()` line has drawn

but with `G.drawline()` there is no line.

In the end, I need to save my picture, but with `e.drawline` i have a black picture.

Comment: So you want to paint points on a panel?

Comment: Yes, but with G.drawline() there is no points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out...note the differences and that I also added a MouseMove() handler for panel1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private class Class1
    {
        public int X1, X2, X3, X4;
    }

    private Class1 Mycl = new Class1();
    private Dictionary<int, Class1> MyDict = new Dictionary<int, Class1>();

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Mycl.X1 = e.X;
            Mycl.X2 = e.Y;
            Mycl.X3 = e.X;
            Mycl.X4 = e.Y;

            Point pt1 = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(Mycl.X1, Mycl.X2));
            Point pt2 = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(Mycl.X3, Mycl.X4));
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(pt1, pt2, panel1.BackColor);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point pt1 = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(Mycl.X1, Mycl.X2));
            Point pt2 = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(Mycl.X3, Mycl.X4));
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(pt1, pt2, panel1.BackColor);

            Mycl.X3 = e.X;
            Mycl.X4 = e.Y;
            pt2 = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(Mycl.X3, Mycl.X4));
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(pt1, pt2, panel1.BackColor);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Mycl.X3 = e.X;
            Mycl.X4 = e.Y;
            MyDict.Add(MyDict.Count + 1, Mycl);
            panel1.Invalidate();
            Mycl = new Class1();
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Black))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Class1> kvp in MyDict)
            {
                Point pl1 = new Point(kvp.Value.X1, kvp.Value.X2);
                Point pl2 = new Point(kvp.Value.X3, kvp.Value.X4);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(MyPen, pl1, pl2);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), panel1.Size));
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Mike\Pictures\SomeImage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's Perfect! and it's work! thank you very much! Now, i'm sitting and understand)))

Comment: Are possible to drow ellipse in ControlPaint? i always have a rechtangle!

Comment: You'd need a much more robust design and approach to handle other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to differentiate between your screen graphics and your bitmap objects graphics ...

here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button button1;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private Bitmap bmp;
        private Point? p1 = null;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 23);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(477, 352);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
            this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
            this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
            this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseUp);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(477, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "write bitmap to file";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(477, 375);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }



        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            p1 = pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p2 = pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1.Value, pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition));
            }
            p1 = null;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (p1 != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1.Value, pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition));
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog=new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.DefaultExt = "bmp";
            dialog.ValidateNames = true;
            dialog.Filter = "Bitmap|*.bmp";
            dialog.AddExtension = true;
            dialog.OverwritePrompt=true;
            var result=dialog.ShowDialog(this);
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var fs = dialog.OpenFile())
                {
                    bmp.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

in the example you can see 2 different DrawLine(...) calls ... the one in the paint event handles on screen painting, which is NOT persisted in the bitmap ... the one in mouse up handles the modifications in the bitmap ...

Comment: try to see it this way: the user clicks and p1 is set ... now with mouse move the picturebox is invalidated so it will repaint ... once it repaints it draws on the SCREEN a line from p1 to the current position of the mouse ... once the mouse is released, a line from p1 to the current position of the mouse is drawn to the BITMAP and p1 is reset to null